# Making callout lines follow feature offset

Tags: qgis, line, offset, callout

I'm looking for a solution to the following problem: Using QGIS 3.16 I'd like to display two point features with the same coordinates. So I set an offset to the symbology of one of them (see attached picture, brown square). This feature also has a label with a callout line. When using the offset, the callout line still starts at the original feature's place.

How can I apply the offset to the callout line starting point as well?

(brown square with offset, line still starts at original coordinates, as shown below)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! Which GIS software do you use ?

Answer (score 1):

An older question, but still highly relevant.

This can be achieved with a *Geometry Generator* expression. Incidentally, this means you can make callouts whatever shape you can think of, provided the expression is valid.

###### Procedure

In the Callouts tab, click the `Line style` selector

[image]

Change the `Symbol layer type` to `Geometry Generator`

[image]

Enter this expression: *(where `5` in this example is the same distance as the symbol offset)*

```sql
make_line(
    start_point($geometry),      -- $geometry is the geometry of the original callout line
    project(                     -- shift the end point of the callout line
        end_point($geometry),
        5,                       -- the distance of your symbol offset
        radians(90)              -- project the point 90 geographic degrees (east), alter according to your symbol offset
    )
)
```

Make sure the `Units` are the same as your symbol offset.

[image]

###### Result

[image]

###### Note

Important to mention is that you can still use other callout options, such as 'Offset from label area' and 'Offset from feature', to fine-tune the position, even after using the Geometry Generator to make the new callout line.