# Making callout lines follow feature offset with line direction as offset parameter

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, direction, callout

I have a problem. I'm offsetting lines with the attribute field "offset".
In the image the blue line is the original geometry.
I was able to retrieve the offset value the attribute. (The callout line is now on the red line).
But lines have a direction and so the offsetvalue depends on their direction.
If i add a minus before offset it moves to the brown line where it should be automatically.

How do I have to change the code to get the geometry direction automatically instead of using the minus symbol which just works for one direction?

[image]

```
make_line(
    start_point($geometry),      
        project(                 
        end_point($geometry),
            -"Offset",            
        radians(90)              
    )
)
```

[image]

The original thread was:
[Making callout lines follow feature offset](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/393210/making-callout-lines-follow-feature-offset/447419?noredirect=1#comment730411_447419)

Answer (score 1):

A problem you face is that the offset of the callout end point is taking place only in the `x` direction, so the end of the callout is not perfectly aligned with the offset line.

Try this expression:

```sql
-- make variables of the start and end points of the original callout  
with_variable('start', start_point($geometry),
    with_variable('end', end_point($geometry),
        make_line(
            @start,
            project(
                @end,
                "Offset",
                azimuth(@start, @end)   -- get the callout line direction for the point projection
            )               
        )
    )
)
```

*You may have to add the minus sign before `"Offset"`, depending on your line directions.*

###### Important

Be sure to enable the `Line orientation dependent position` option in the label placement tab:

[image]

###### Result

[image]